# IndexError, why list appear to be empty when evaluated from if statement?

Tags: python, bigdata

I'm trying to read from an huge file (1GB) and trying to go cheap on memory usage while doing so.
This is my code:

```
with open('abitmorelinesdec.dat') as data_f:
    i=0
    line=[]
    for lines in data_f:
        i=i+1
        line = np.array(list(filter(None,lines.strip().split(' ')))[4:],dtype=int)
        if line[4] == 0:
            print('ok')
```

It does output the following:

```
if line[4] == 0:

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

If i try instead to run this:

```
with open('abitmorelinesdec.dat') as data_f:
    i=0
    line=[]
    for lines in data_f:
        i=i+1
        line = np.array(list(filter(None,lines.strip().split(' ')))[4:],dtype=int)
    if i==100:
        print(line) 
        print(len(line))
```

Spyder does output:

```
[3459 3458 3457 ... 3464 3460 3464]
1024
```

This shows that python is correctely treating line as a list with 1024 elements just 'a moment' before the if statement is declared.
What I'm missing here?

You can find a fraction of the file here: https://pastebin.com/FPFWAsxP

Thanks you a lot in advance

Comment: `line` is *not* a list, it is an array

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hi there! you are right, i'm sorry for the bad wording. I'm a new coder. this happens with lists too though.

Comment: Instead of doing `i = i + 1` in the loop, try looking into `enumerate` in python. Much more pythonic and clean. (This isn't an answer)

Comment: Also `len` and `np.array` will work nicely but that doesn't mean that it's a `list`.

Comment: @hqkhan thanks for the suggestions, i will look into enumerate asap. also, yup check my previous comment about misnaming.. sorry!

Comment: Is the `if i==100:` line indented correctly? It's essential, as you know-- edit your post if not.

Comment: It's hard to tell what is wrong because we can't see the data as it's too big. One suggestion is to find out at which iteration of `i` the error occurs. Then try looking at the line to see if there is anything there (seems like there isn't -- maybe problem with data?). You can also wrap the lines where you do access line in `try` and `except` statement and perform some debugging that way.

Comment: @alexis, hey thanks! it is indented correctely, edited op

Comment: So, your file has exactly 100 lines? Because the `if` statement is only evaluated once.

Comment: You could add some logic before you hit that `if` statement such as checking the length of `line` using `len`. For instance, `if len(line) < 3: continue` to skip that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what your line-reading code does with the lines you read:

```
>>> line = np.array(list(filter(None,"0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10".strip().split(' ')))[4:],dtype=int)
>>> line[4]
8
```

Yup, it works correctly. Conclusion: Your input file has some empty or short lines. Why don't you loop to print the length of each line, and you'll see for yourself.

```
with open('abitmorelinesdec.dat') as data_f:
    for inpline in data_f:
        print(len(np.array(list(filter(None,inpline.strip().split(' ')))[4:],dtype=int)))
```

Comment: Yup, you beat me to it. There's probably an empty line in the data which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this **is not an answer**. but this is the easiest way to write the code that might point to where you problem is. it'll give you more information on where the offending line is.

```
with open('abitmorelinesdec.dat') as data_f:
    i=0
    line=[]
    for lines in data_f:
        i=i+1
        line = np.array(list(filter(None,lines.strip().split(' ')))[4:],dtype=int)
        try:
            fifth_element = line[4]
        except IndexError:
            print(f"error at line {i}")
            print(line)
            raise IndexError
        if fifth_element == 0:
            print('ok')
```